# Visual Studio error on new project creation

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Situation.
I have Web developer Express Studio 2008 installed on my system.
Until recent windows update it worked fine, but about 2 weeks ago it start giving me an error every time I attempt to create any new project. Screen shot of an error below:
[Express 2008 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOfqa.png)

[image]

I did try to do windows restore to point before update and it did not worked.
As a next step I installed Visual Studio 2010(same result) and VS 2015 same result but a bit more descriptive error. Screen show below.
[VS 2015 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAhDc.png)

[image]

But there is no clear information on Microsoft MSDN forums about this error or how to fix it.
I did try to do reset(devenv.exe\resetsettings) but so far no luck.
Any idea what is going on and how to fix this?

Right now I can not create ANY new project and some of older projects are not opening as well. There is no system of or any kind of similarity between projects which opens or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly vague error as the dll in question isn't listed here and 0x8007045a is just the error code for this dll initialization error. As a next step in troubleshooting to find the issue (outside of a windows repair) I'd go ahead and run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) and watch the file system activity for Visual Studio (once you see devenv.exe show up, right click on it and include just that process.

There's a blog post with some troubleshooting steps [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/04/29/unable-to-load-dll-dllname-dll-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-failed-0x8007045a/) but really though, you need to find which library is the culprit to track down what you'll need to reinstall (likely from a system or shared library side).